# jsp code for connecting to hbase for fetching data from hbase?

Tags: jsp, hbase

What is the jsp code for making a connection to hbase ? I have to retrieve data from hbase so for it first I have to make connection to hbase first.

Answer (score 0):

it is the same as the normal java client. you can use the link below.

http://www.slideshare.net/mobile/martyhall/hadoop-tutorial-hbase-part-3-java-client-api